# Save food dishes: MySQL or MongoDB?

Tags: mysql, mongodb

What would be the best database system to store a lot of food dishes. Knowing that a dish can have variations. A small pizza is cheaper then a large pizza. And if you for example want extra olives on your pizza, you need to pay extra.

I am doubting between MySQL (which I am already familiar with) or MongoDB (of which I have heard good things but have zero experience in).

In MySQL I would use the following structure:

[image: MySQL structure for dishes]

You have a dish, and each dish has their variations. The price is stored in the variations. There is also a table which holds the extra options and the extra price for that options.

In MongoDB I guess I'd make a document like this:

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "Pizza Hawaii",
    description: "Pizza with cheese and pineapple.",
    variations: {
        "small": "9.50",
        "medium": "12.50",
        "large": "15.00"
    },
    extras: {
        "olives": "0.50",
        "extra_cheese": "1.50"
    }
}
```

Which seams pretty flexible. But I have no clue on what technology would suit this project the best.

**Edit:**

Some SELECT examples. Let's say I want to replicate the following purchase-window.

[image: Pizza purchase window.]

I'd use the following SELECT to display the name and description of the Pizza:

```
SELECT name, description FROM dish WHERE ID = 1;

+--------------+---------------------------------+
| name         | description                     |
+--------------+---------------------------------+
| Pizza Hawaii | Pizza with cheese and pineapple |
+--------------+---------------------------------+
```

This select to get the dropdown menu for small/medium/large:

```
SELECT variation, price FROM dish_variations WHERE dish = 1;

+-----------+-------+
| variation | price |
+-----------+-------+
| Small     |   9.5 |
| Medium    |  12.5 |
| Large     |    15 |
+-----------+-------+
```

And the last query to display the checkboxes with all the extra options:

```
SELECT extra, price FROM dish_extras WHERE dish = 1;

+--------------+-------+
| extra        | price |
+--------------+-------+
| Olives       |   1.5 |
| Extra Cheese |   1.5 |
+--------------+-------+
```

Comment: Show us some `SELECTs`.

Comment: @RickJames View edit.

Comment: Did the user come to the website with "I want whatever id=1 gives me"?  Perhaps there is another `SELECT` from a page that listed Pizzas, then one that listed varieties of Pizzas?

Comment: @RickJames The user comes to the website selecting "I want pizza/sushi/kebab/..." and then get a list of restaurants. In this case he selected restaurant with ID 1. It is NOT the case that a list of dishes is listed before a restaurant is selected.

Comment: If you are presenting a few lists (restaurants > menu items > options), there is no "best DB.  Any of them will suffice.  Easy option:  use the DB you are familiar with.  Learning option:  use a different DB.

Comment: Please refer to my MongoDB flowchart: "Should I use Mongo?" -> "No"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW, this is a common problem typically handled by RDBMS and I don't see anything specifically advantageous about using a NoSQL solution (like MongoDB) over a relational database.

The different `Toppings` that can be chosen for a pizza are a type of dimension for `Pizzas`. They inherently have a one-to-many relationship with an ordered `Pizza`. The different `Sizes` are another dimension of `Pizzas`. The relationship is one-to-one.

I'd actually model this similar to how a custom manufacturing schema would look like. A configurable `Pizza` item has multiple children `Toppings` items. Once ordered, you can save that configuration to a `BOM` (Bill of Materials) type of table that stores configured `Pizzas`. `Size` is a property of the parent `Pizza` item. Each item has its own `UnitPrice` which gets multiplied by the `Size` and / or factors such as *double-toppings* being selected, etc.

The schema for this type of problem is fairly standard and doesn't change frequently. NoSQL databases are useful for ill-defined schemas, schemas that change shape frequently, or schemas that are outside the control of the developers (such as consumption of 3rd party APIs) and that are liable to change often as well.